Relating covariances for (θ, Χ) and (cos(θ), Χ)
From basic error propagation rules, we have σ(cos(θ)) = |sin(θ)| σ(θ).
Question: does something similar hold for the covariance cov(cos(θ),X) and cov(θ,Χ)?

Hi. Welcome to CV. This is a MathJax-enabled site. Please use this
facility to typeset your mathematical expressions for better
legibility. For a quick guide, check this Meta CV post:
Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated.

Can explain this problem better? What do you mean that $i,j$ "takes values" from ... ? These are indices of a matrix not random quantities.

@AdamO it is a 5x5 matrix. The 5 variables of the multivariate Gaussian are cos(δ), a, b, c, and d. Essentially, I want to get the covariance matrix for parameters δ, a, b, c, d (and then for parameters θ, a, b, c, d).

Additionally, could you explain the mechanism whereby "considering" a subscript induces a change in a property of a distribution?

@whuber the covariance matrix estimates the errors in recovering the true values of the parameters cos(δ), a, b, c, d. I want the covariance matrix that estimates the errors in recovering the true values of the parameters δ, a, b, c, d (and then θ, a, b, c, d).

Would it be fair, then, to interpret your question as asking (a) how the variances of $\delta$ and $\cos\delta$ are related when the latter is approximately Gaussian (it obviously cannot be exactly Gaussian, because cosines are bounded) and (b) how the covariances of $(\delta,X)$ and $(\cos\delta,X)$ are related when the latter is approximately multivariate Gaussian?

@whuber that sounds right.

Please, then, edit your post to make that explicit: that will help limit the chance of getting irrelevant or erroneous answers based on misinterpretations.  (We can't rely on everyone reading through all the comments.) // It might be worthwhile remarking that there will not be a definite answer and that--in particular--the variance of $\delta$ can be infinite, no matter how small the variance of $\cos\delta$ might be. If that would be bad news, consider explaining more about what $\delta$ is and what assumptions you can make about its distribution.

Re "basic error propagation rules:" they don't necessarily apply here.  You need to make strong assumptions about the distribution of $\theta$ to use them.

@whuber thank you for your useful comments. I made the same assumptions as for the variance and by computing the Jacobian I was able to find the corresponding relation for the covariance.

Unfortunately that can be arbitrarily bad.  Consider a natural number $n$ and let $\psi$ be a random number with probability $1/n$ of equaling $(j+1/2)\pi$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1.$ Let $\epsilon$ independently have a Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and tiny variance $\sigma^2\ll(\pi/2)^2$ and set $\theta=\psi+\epsilon.$ You can check that $\cos\theta$ is approximately Gaussian with approximate variance $\sigma^2$ while the variance of $\theta$ is approximately $\sigma^2+(n\pi)^2/12.$  Since $n$ can be arbitrarily large, there's no upper bound to the variance of $\theta.$

"σ(cos(θ)) = |sin(θ)| σ(θ)" This is a linear approximation for small variations.

Thank you both for your comments.
